# How to insert data in 1..1 relationship C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, sql-insert

So, I have two tables: Employee and Address. Every Employee MUST have an Address.

EmployeeId is PK in Employee table, it is Identity and auto increment
AddressId is PK in Address table, it is Identity and auto increment

When I want to create a new record I am getting **`A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column:`**

I wasted a whole day and still do not know how to fix it. Plus I am beginner in DataBase programming. I am using entity framework and C#:

I am uploading pictures for more information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8GXu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSGc1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3tS8.png)

Comment: So I tried first to add the Address and then the Employee, still the same error.

Comment: your error is saying you the FK cannot be computed/set, as is it database generated. Usually one-to-one relationships are bad design. What you can do though is set an additional FK, remove the identity mapping from one column or use a transaction to set both simultaneously. The tutorial http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/add-one-to-one-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx is using the transaction approach I think - I doubt they use identity insert, however that would require the use of transactions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed IsIdentity on Address table AddressId, but still a primary key. And this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of a wrongly placed foreign key in the table.

Chrck in relationship especially foreign key . Delete the schema . You need to update the EDMX files (and not enough to "refresh" the table from the model, you need to remove and add the table again in the model).

Answer (score 0):

1..1 relationships are not really possible in relational databases. The problem is that there is no order of inserting the entities that does not violate the other foreign key. If you insert employee first the Address does not exist yet, but you can not insert the address without the employee.

Therefor my recommendation for your exact question is changing it to 0-1..1 relationship. Every employee **MUST** have an address, but you don't *really* need the employee for the adress. Then insert the adress first, assign to the employee and insert employee next. Then save in one transaction.

Personal advice: If your relation truly is 1..1 there is no reason to split it into two tables. The point of tables and relations is avoiding redundancy. However an adress table that **MUST** have an employee can not be used for anything else anyway, so you might as well just add the adress columns to the employee table. This does not only work, but is also faster.

Database design and class design best practices are not identical. What should be split into two classes in C# might be a single table and vice versa.

Comment: So what should I do ? :D

Comment: Do you need two tables for other reasons? Use 0-1 .. 1, otherwise go for a single table.